# How to compile the llm library with nix

Tags: rust, nix, large-language-model

I tried to install the [llm library](https://github.com/rustformers/llm) with nix.

You just have to do that:

```
git clone https://github.com/rustformers/llm.git
nix build
```

Unfortunately it fails:

> error: builder for
> '/nix/store/zllzqwj422zqrsl24lgr6j5y0m4c1mx7-rust-workspace-deps-unknown.drv'
> failed with exit code 101;
> last 10 log lines:
> > [naersk] RUSTFLAGS:
> > [naersk] CARGO_BUILD_RUSTFLAGS:
> > [naersk] CARGO_BUILD_RUSTFLAGS (updated): --remap-path-prefix /nix/store/772s1031nnkf5b5qzw55g6nkir1k2jjc-dependencies=/sources
> > building
> > cargo build $cargo_release -j "$NIX_BUILD_CORES" --message-format=$cargo_message_format
> > error: package `half v2.3.1` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.70 or newer, while the currently active rustc version
> is 1.69.0
> > Either upgrade to rustc 1.70 or newer, or use
> > cargo update -p half@2.3.1 --precise ver
> > where `ver` is the latest version of `half` supporting rustc 1.69.0
> > [naersk] cargo returned with exit code 101, exiting
> For full logs, run 'nix log /nix/store/zllzqwj422zqrsl24lgr6j5y0m4c1mx7-rust-workspace-deps-unknown.drv'.

You can see in the input of flake.nix that nix unstable is used.

```
  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = github:nixos/nixpkgs/nixpkgs-unstable;
    naersk.url = github:nix-community/naersk;
    flake-utils.url = github:numtide/flake-utils;
  };
```

if you search for [rustc in nix unstable package list](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=unstable&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=rustc), you will find 1.70
but in [rustc in nix stable package list](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=23.05&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=rustc) you will find 1.69

Why is rust 1.69 (rust from nix stable) used if nix unstable is the input?

**First explaination that fails**

rustc package is used only in  devShells.default not in packages.default.

packages.default is build from the source with the help of naersk that probably use nix stable.

I means that

```
    nix develop -i
    cargo build --release
```

should work
THat is not the case

> error: package `half v2.3.1` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.70 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.69.0
> Either upgrade to rustc 1.70 or newer, or use

indeed
rustc -.version

> 1.69

Comment: To me, this looks like a bug in their flake. IMO, you should open an issue.

Answer (score 0):

it fix the problem but doesn´t answer why rust 1.69 is used by default.

add rustup in the flake

```
      packages = [ cargo rustup rustc rust-analyzer rustfmt cmake ];
```

then execute

```
     nix develop -i
     rustup toolchain install 1.70.0
     cargo build --release
```

the build fails but for another reason